# `let` operation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Ηow can I separate options within brackets `[...]` so that is affected only the current command;

For example, I want  dashed lines only here `(0,0) |- (A) [dashed]` .

Could someone give a detailed explanation of the use of `let` operation. The examples in the pgf manual at 150p.  I think is not enough to understand the use of the `let` operation in-depth, at least for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,cap=round,>=latex]
    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-3.0cm,-3.0cm) grid (3.0cm,3.0cm);
    \draw[->] (-2.5cm,0cm) -- (2.5cm,0cm);
    \draw[->] (0cm,-2.5cm) -- (0cm,2.5cm);

    \coordinate (center) at (0.cm,0.cm) ;
    \coordinate (A) at (1.5cm,1.cm);
    \filldraw [black] (center) circle (0.04cm) node [left] {$Ο$};

    \draw let  
      \p1 = ($(A)-(center)$),
      \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)}
    in
      (center) circle (\n1)
      (A) circle  (0.1cm)[fill color = black]
      (0,0) |- (A) [dashed]
      (center)  -- (A);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: The `let` command is always used within a `\path` (or `\draw` or `\fill`) command, and you can't change the drawing options within a `\path`. In your example, there's no reason to have the lines from `(A) circle ...` to `(center) -- (A);` in the same `\draw` command as the `let` keyword (you're not using `\p1`, `\n1`, or `\n2` in any of them), so you can just move them to their own `\draw` commands.

Comment: I'm trying to learn to programing in tikz. I understand what you mean, but the question is can I have separate options on each individual command. From what you say probably not

Comment: You can have separate options only on separate `\path` commands, but since a `let` keyword is always part of a `\path` you can't use separate options for different parts of a `let` keyword.

Comment: So to do this the only way as saying the manual is ... (from manual: ...Note that the effect of a let operation is local to the body of the let operation. If you wish to access a
computed coordinate outside the body, you must use a coordinate path operation.... page 152)...So there is no other way to have separate option, sorry for the insistence just trying to clear up ...

Comment: Using a `coordinate` in the `let` operation is probably the clearest way to do it. However, you could also use an `edge` operation if you absolutely want to avoid this. The `(center)  -- (A)` could be replaced by `(center)  edge [red, solid] (A)`, for example, but it gets more unwieldy for the other lines. The orthogonal line would have to be expressed using `(0,0) edge [to path=(\tikztostart) |- (\tikztotarget), ultra thick, solid, blue] (A)`, for instance (though you could simplify this by defining custom styles).

Comment: If you want to give this as an answer ... so that I can be accepted as the correct answer...maybe need to change the title to `let and edge operation in tikz`.

Comment: Sorry my friends for my English sometimes I laugh with myself .... do not get me wrong

Comment: It's quite ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `let` operation can only be used within a `\path` (or `\draw` or `\fill`...) command. Drawing options like `line width`, `dashed`, or the color, can not be changed in a single path, therefore they cannot be changed within a `let` command.

In your concrete example, you don't need to have the two circles and the straight lines in the same path as the `let` command: Only the large circle actually uses the result of the `let` calculation. In this case, the easiest thing would be to just move the other parts into their own `\path`s.

In general, however, there are basically two different approaches for using the results from the `let` operation for paths with different drawing styles:

- You can name coordinates using the `coordinate (<name>) at (<coordinate>)` keyword. These can then be used in other `\path` commands.
- You can use the `edge` keyword, which tells TikZ to not draw the path segment immediately, but to execute it as a separate path after the main path is finished, which makes it possible to use different drawing styles. For straight lines, its as easy as replacing `(A) -- (B)` with `(A) edge [red] (B)`. For more complicated constructs, you'll have to adjust the value of the `to path` key: An orthogonal path `(A) -| (B)` could be expressed as `(A) edge [to path=(\tikztostart) |- (\tikztotarget), red] (B)`.

Answer (score 15):

Jake's answer is perfect. The next answer is for the case that you need to do more complex calculation not easily done by simple expressions

I think it's not very fine to do calculations and drawing operations at the same time. And if you use several calculations and several drawings, you complicate the code.

**A) Path and drawing**

The `path` begins with `\draw` (exactly `\path[draw]`) and ends with `;`. Drawing one path means  you take one pencil with one color . You cannot change the pencil inside the path.

So if you want to draw two circles with different colors you need to use two paths, example :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw    [blue] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
    \draw    [red]  (2,0) circle (1 cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But if you write

```
\draw [red]   (0,0) circle (1 cm) [blue,fill=green!20]
              (2,0) circle (2 cm);
```

then the circles are in blue and the disks are green. Blue because it's the last option the color, and the fill color is applied to  the path.

**B) Path and calculations**

Now if you need to do some calculations to draw the circles

In the pgfmanual there is this example : 
I  used longer names, but  I have to use curly braces `\p{AB}` insted of `\p1`. The code is more readable. 
Remark : in the next example you can avoid the `let` operation with the `through` library.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} 
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate [label=left:$A$]  (A) at (0,0);
          \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (1.25,0.25);
          \draw let \p{AB}        = ($ (B) - (A) $),
                    \n{radius} = {veclen(\x{AB},\y{AB})}
                in
                  (A) circle (\n{radius})
                  (B) circle (\n{radius});
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

The two circles are in black now if I want the first circle in red and the secon in blue and if I want to calculate once the AB, I need to do this

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate [label=left:$A$]  (A) at (0,0);
      \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (1.25,0.25);
      \draw let 
                \p{AB} = ($ (B) - (A) $),
                \n{radius} = {veclen(\x{AB},\y{AB})}
            in 
            \pgfextra{\xdef\sameradius{\n{radius}}}
               [red]  (A)  circle (\n{radius}) ;
        \draw  [blue] (B)  circle (\sameradius) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Explanation : `\p{AB}` is local to the path operation and you can use the result outside the first path. You need to pass the tikz register `\n{radius}` to  tex. But you need to use a global macro to jump outside the group. It's why I used `\xdef` !

**C) Your case**

In your case (if `myradius` is the radius of the big circle) you wrote

```
\draw   (center) circle (\myradius pt)
        (A) circle  (0.1cm) 
        (0,0) |- (A) [dashed]
        (center)  -- (A);
```

Here you have only one path. (the beginning is `\draw`equivalent to `\path[draw]` and the end is `;`).

All the path is drawn with the "dashed" option. If you want to change the options then you need three paths

```
\draw   (center) circle (\myradius pt);
\fill   (A) circle  (0.1cm) ; % fill the little circle
\draw [dashed]  (0,0) |- (A) % dash the lines
        (center)  -- (A);
```

**D) In the Old Days, before the `let operation`**

Perhaps it's interesting to know what it was necessary to do before the `let' operation. This operation now is used to avoid the next TeX code. This kind of code sometimes is useful when you want to create complex operations  and if you want a code  more flexible and faster

First we need to get the coordinates of the vector `$(A)-(center)$`. We need to use the macro `\pgfpointdiff`. The result is inside `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`. We need to work between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because we need to use `@` like a simple letter.

Then we calculate the length (A)--(center) with `\pgfmathveclen`. The result is in `\pgfmathresult`. (unity is `pt`). This is raw code and it's preferable to take some precautions when we use `\pgf@x}` , `\pgf@y` and `\pgfmathresult`.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}%
             {\pgfpointanchor{center}{center}}%
\pgfmathveclen{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}
 \makeatother
```

This is raw code and it's preferable to take some precautions when we use `\pgf@x}` , `\pgf@y` and `\pgfmathresult`.

Now we can stock the mathresult inside a macro `\myradius` and it's more easy to use and to read the code

```
\makeatletter
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}%
             {\pgfpointanchor{center}{center}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{veclen(\xdim,\ydim)}
\makeatother
```

But It's possible to do something better because now we have `pgflastxy` and we can avoid `makeatletter`

Firstly we create `\xdim` and `ydim` to stock the dimensions and we use `\pgfgetlastxy` to get the dimensions of the vector.

```
\newdimen\xdim\newdimen\ydim
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}%
             {\pgfpointanchor{center}{center}}%
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdim}{\ydim}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{veclen(\xdim,\ydim)}
```

The complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,cap=round,>=latex]
    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-3.0cm,-3.0cm) grid (3.0cm,3.0cm);
    \draw[->] (-2.5cm,0cm) -- (2.5cm,0cm);
    \draw[->] (0cm,-2.5cm) -- (0cm,2.5cm);

    \coordinate (center) at (0.cm,0.cm) ;
    \coordinate (A) at (1.5cm,1.cm);
    \filldraw [black] (center) circle (0.04cm) node [left] {$Ο$};
% calculation (the let part)
\newdimen\xdim\newdimen\ydim
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}%
             {\pgfpointanchor{center}{center}}%
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdim}{\ydim}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{veclen(\xdim,\ydim)}

\draw   (center) circle (\myradius pt);
\fill   (A) circle  (0.1cm) ;
\draw [dashed]  (0,0) |- (A) 
        (center)  -- (A);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Instead of

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,cap=round,>=latex]
    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-3.0cm,-3.0cm) grid (3.0cm,3.0cm);
    \draw[->] (-2.5cm,0cm) -- (2.5cm,0cm);
    \draw[->] (0cm,-2.5cm) -- (0cm,2.5cm);

    \coordinate (center) at (0.cm,0.cm) ;
    \coordinate (A) at (1.5cm,1.cm);
    \filldraw [black] (center) circle (0.04cm) node [left] {$Ο$};
    \draw  
       let 
           \p{Acenter}        = ($ (A) - (center) $),
           \n{radius} = {veclen(\x{Acenter},\y{Acenter})}
        in
     (center) circle (\n{radius});
    \fill   (A) circle  (0.1cm) ;
    \draw [dashed]  (0,0) |- (A) 
        (center)  -- (A);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. Regrettable fact that we can not choose two correct answers.