# Connected `to path`s

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

Consider the following

```
\tikzset{
  myline/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)}}
}
```

and

```
\draw (0,0) edge[myline] (1,1) edge[myline] (2,0);
```

Now, it seems like `\tikztostart` does not reset on the second edge command, and remains to be (0,0)?

More specifically, at the second "call" to edge, I thought `\tikztostart` would have the value `(1,1)` and not `(2,0)`.

Is there e.g. an alternative control sequence to `\tikztostart` that would make this work?

Feel free to specify and edit the question title

---

### Runnable example code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  myline/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % With edges
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,1)}]
      \draw (0,0) edge[myline] (1,1) edge[myline] (2,0);
      \node[below] at (1,0){With \texttt{edge}s};
    \end{scope}
    % With --, which gives "expected" results
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
      \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0);
      \node[below] at (1,0){With \texttt{--} (expected)};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Use `to` instead of `edge` and read page 253 of the manual.

Comment: @HenriMenke that would work, but then having multiple styles for multiple lines breaks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103285/let-operation-in-tikz. I'll read the page in the manual!

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799) you can find a way to get the desired outcome: `every edge/.append code = {%
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={(\currenttarget)}}}`. However, if you explain what you are really up to, there might be nicer way. (I guess you are looking for `show path construction` with which you can change the line style during the path.)

Comment: @marmot Interesting! Thanks :) Explaining what I am really up to is just too much work -- both for me and the community x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This code by Hood Chatman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799) allows you to get the desired result with edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  myline/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)}}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % With edges
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,1)},every edge/.append code={% 
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable 
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={(\currenttarget)}}}]
      \draw (0,0) edge[myline] (1,1) edge[myline] (2,0);
      \node[below] at (1,0){With \texttt{edge}s};
    \end{scope}
    % With --, which gives "expected" results
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
      \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0);
      \node[below] at (1,0){With \texttt{--} (expected)};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you zoom in at the top you will see that it is not quite the same,

[image]

simply because split the path in two pieces rather than one.